# call ag-grid-react's component's method from cellrenderer component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, ag-grid-react, react-functional-component

I have a functional component called `GenericGrid`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { AgGridReact } from "ag-grid-react";

const GenericGrid = props => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  const gridApi = useRef();

  const onGridReady = params => {
    const { defaultFilter } = props;
    gridApi.current = params.api;

    const datasource = getServerDataSource(
      gridApi.current,
      {
        size: AppConstants.PAGE_SIZE,
        url: baseUrl,
        defaultFilter
      }
    );

    gridApi.current.setServerSideDatasource(datasource);
  };  

  ...  // < == other methods omitted for brevity

  const onAddNew = () => setVisible(true);

  return (
   <>
    {!visible && (
      <div className="ag-theme-material gridSize">
        <AgGridReact
          reactNext={true}
          onCellValueChanged={onCellValueChanged}
          onGridReady={onGridReady}
          columnDefs={columnDefs}
          pagination={true}
          context={GenericGrid}  // <== passed the component in context
          onSelectionChanged={onRowSelect}
          {...props.options}
        ></AgGridReact>
      </div>
    )}
    {visible &&
      clonedElementWithMoreProps(addNewComponent, {
        visible,
        onHide: () => setVisible(false),
        dialogBtnLoading: createNewProgress,
        onSubmit: create
      })}
   </>
   );
}

export default GenericGrid;
```

Now there's a column def for the last column which has `cellRendererFramework` like so:

```
if (field.name === "ViewDetails") {
  return {
    field: field.name,
    colId: field.name,
    headerName: field.displayName,
    sortable: false,
    cellRendererFramework: params => {

      console.log("params.context", params.context); // <== prints the definition of 'GenericGrid'
      console.log('params.context.onAddNew', params.context.onAddNew) // <== but this prints undefined

      return (
        <button className="btn btn-sm p-0 btn-link text-cm-primary"
          onClick={params.context.onAddNew}  
          >
          View Details
        </button>
      );
    }
  };
}
```

Now on the click of a button in the last column, I want to call function `onAddNew` or even better if possible the `setValue` directly, declared in the `GenericGrid` component.

As per the official documentation, this works for `class` based component where context is passed like this: `context = { componentParent: this }`. But since my component is functional component I directly passed `GenericGrid` in context assuming it would work but it doesn't.

Comment: do you check cellRenderer not cellRendererFramework? maybe that was problem

Comment: @mansourlotfi No, it doesn't work with cellRenderer.

Comment: I got a bit further by declaring a function in the parent and then settings the context as follows: const context = {componentParent: (props) => foo(props)}; I get a runtime error in the renderer (not shown) that foo is not a function. I am investigating this link: https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/3283 to see if this resolves the issue. The crux of it is to use a useRef hook